# Web2py - Show a different reference field than id

Tags: python, web2py

using this example in 
Model:

```
db.define_table('person', 
    Field('name'), 
    format='%(name)s')

db.define_table('dog',
    Field('name'),
    Field('owner'), db.person)
```

Controller:

```
def list():
    dog_list = db().select(db.dog.ALL)
    return dict(dog_list=dog_list)
```

View:

```
{{for item in dog_list:}}
 ...
{{=item.name}} {{=item.owner}}
...
{{pass}}
```

Result sample:

```
Dogname1 1
Dogname2 2
Dogname3 1
```

How can I show in my view the owner's name and not their id?

I'm need my own table and I can't use SQLTABLE or another grid-table solution for this...

Thanks in advance.

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a [recursive select](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#Recursive-selects) via `{{=item.owner.name}}`, but that will do a separate query for each record. For efficiency, you might instead want to do a [join](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#Inner-joins).

Comment: Excellent, only replacing {{=item.owner}} with {{=item.owner.name}} do the task. Thanks.